# React V18 FC: Parent and Child Components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to create a reusable components in my website. I have created a following components

```
const Header: React.FC = () => …
const Content: React.FC = () => …

const MyCustomComponent = {Header, Content};
export default MyCustomComponent;
```

From other components I can able to consume like below

```
import MyCustomComponent …
…
<MyCustomComponent.Header />
<MyCustomComponent.Content />
```

But my expectation is, those component should be wrapped like below

```
import MyCustomComponent …
…
<MyCustomComponent>
<MyCustomComponent.Header />
<MyCustomComponent.Content />
</MyCustomComponent>
```

My Goal is I can able to pass more children props to the wrapper as well. At the same time children component should be call under parent component.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing that stops you from doing this:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <MyCustomC>
      <MyCustomC.C1 />
      <MyCustomC.C2 />
      <SomeOther />
    </MyCustomC>
  );
}

export function MyCustomC({ children }) {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}

export function C1() {
  return <div>111</div>;
}

export function C2() {
  return <div>222</div>;
}

export function SomeOther() {
  return <div>333</div>;
}

MyCustomC.C1 = C1;
MyCustomC.C2 = C2;
```

except that such usage of components is not documented anywhere and might have inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: Thanks Serguei. This one was not working with >18. It require to declare the props for the children.

Comment: I didn't notice you were using Typescript. Since it's working in JS, it also should work in TS with proper typings.

Answer (score -1):

In React(>18) the following code works. Thanks for the support

```
export const App = () => {
  return (
    <MyCustomComponent>
      <MyCustomComponent.Header>
              Header Content
      </MyCustomComponent.Header>

      <MyCustomComponent.Footer>
             Footer Content
      </MyCustomComponent.Footer>
    </MyCustomComponent>
  );
};
```

in MyCustomComponent.tsx

```
const CustomHeader: FC<PropsWithChildren> = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <div className='custom-header'>{children}</div>
    )
};

const CustomFooter: FC<PropsWithChildren> = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <div className='custom-footer'>{children}</div>
    )
};

const MyCustomComponent: FC<PropsWithChildren> = ({children}) => {
   return children;
});

MyCustomComponent.Header = CustomHeader;

MyCustomComponent.Footer = CustomFooter;
 

export default MyCustomComponent;
```